# Why do I have two remote master branches?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

When I use the `git branch` command, it displays only one local branch: `master`

However, when I use the `git branch -a` command, it displays the initial `master` branch as well as two remote master branches:

`remotes/wilhelm/master`

`remotes/origin/master`

**Why do I have two remote branches and how do I delete the extra branch without deleting my remote repo?**

Comment: It's not an "extra" branch; evidently you have a `master` branch in each of your remote repos.  If you *really* want to delete a remote branch, then refer to the answers e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm confused; I only have one remote repository but two references to the same repo. Is this an error on my part?

Comment: @Wilhelm how do you know that they're both the same repo? What's the output of `git remote -v`? Oh wait, you already removed it right? Well, so much for that...well, what's the output anyways? Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two remote repositories.
Of course everyone of them has a master branch, so you have two remote master branches.

You can remove remotes with

```
git remote remove <name>
```

This will **not** delete the repository, only your local repo will not track the remote repo any more.

Comment: I tried removing `remotes/wilhelm/master` with `git remote remove remotes/wilhelm/master` but received the error `error: Could not remove config section 'remote.remotes/wilhelm/master'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. You have to use `git remote remove wilhelm`

Comment: This removes `[remote "Wilhelm"]` from my `.git/config` file but the remote branch still appears when I call `git branch -a`

Comment: Then you probably have an tracking branch, this one can be removed with `git branch -d <branch>`. But it seems your repo is a little bit broken. Perhaps, you should completely remove it and clone it once again. This is normally faster than fixing a broken repo…

Comment: @toydarian you can't remove tracking branches with `git branch -d`, you need to pass the `--remotes` or `-r` flag with it, i.e. `git branch -dr`. Using `git remote remove` should've removed all remote-tracking branches for the remote though. It even says so in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually removing the branch from my `.git/refs/remotes/` folder.

I wouldn't recommend any one do this unless:

- absolutely necessary
- or you have difficulty letting go [as I do]